# How to determine why GitVersion chose a specific base version?

Tags: gitversion

I am using GitVersion (version 3.5.3 if it matters), and getting some unexpected results; specifically the produced version has an unexpected commit count portion. Looking at the log I can see the commit count is calculated correctly, but the base version used by GitVersion is wrong (or at least not what I thought it would be).

However the log file for GitVersion is less than helpful, it just lists a series of tags, then a long list of merge bases, and at the end it just says which base version it decided to use.

Can GitVersion let me know somehow why it chose that specific base version?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the output that you are seeing?  Or is this on public repo?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark It's a private repo. I'm looking through the GitVersion source at the moment to understand its decision.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, you already checked or not; but it is explained how they calculate base version and also new versions in their [documentation](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/how-it-works/)

UPDATE: Added main information from documentation.

**Architecture**

GitVersion has three distict steps for calculating versions in v3.0.

- If the current commit is tagged, the tag is used and build metadata (Excluding commit count) is added. The other two steps will not execute
- A set of strategies are evaluated to decide on the base version and
  some metadata about that version. These strategies include
  HighestReachableTag, NextVersionInConfig, MergedBranchWithVersion,
  VersionInBranchName etc
- The highest base version is selected, using that base version the new
  version is calculated.

Visually it looks something like this: 
[image]

**Base Version Strategies**

- *HighestTagBaseVersionStrategy* - Finds the highest reachable tag from
  the current branch
- *VersionInBranchBaseVersionStrategy* - Extracts version information
  from the branch name. eg release/3.0.0 will find 3.0.0
- *ConfigNextVersionBaseVersionStrategy* - Returns the version from the
  GitVersion.yaml file
- *MergeMessageBaseVersionStrategy* - Finds version numbers from merge
  messages. eg.
  *Merge 'release/3.0.0' into 'master'* will return *3.0.0*
- *FallbackBaseVersionStrategy* - Always returns 0.1.0 for new
  repositories

Each strategy needs to return an instance of BaseVersion which has the following properties

- *Source* - Description of the source. eg `Merge message 'Merge
  'release/3.0.0' into 'master''
- *ShouldIncrement* - Some strategies should have the version
  incremented, others do not. eg  *ConfigNextVersionBaseVersionStrategy*
  returns false, *HighestTagBaseVersionStrategy* returns true
- *SemanticVersion* - SemVer of the base version strategy
- *BaseVersionSource* - Sha of the source. Commits will be counted from
  this Sha. Can be null (eg ConfigNextVersionBaseVersionStrategy
  returns null)
- *BranchNameOverride* - When *useBranchName* or *{BranchName}* is used in
  the tag configuration, this allows the branch name to be changed by a
  base version. VersionInBranchBaseVersionStrategy uses this to strip
  out anything before the first - or /. So foo ends up being evaluated
  as foo. If in doubt, just use null

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41962010/edit) your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks for information , you are completely right :)

Comment: @nzrytmn but how exactly the base version strategy is chosen? Do I need to specify it in config?